# Intersection of two sets of vectors

Tags: r

I have two sets of 11 vectors, each vector has about 8000 elements.

I wish to make a matrix of 11x11 showing the length of intersections between all possible combinations of the vectors.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thanks

---

#### A smaller example: two sets with three vectors each.

First Set:

```
V1 <- c("a", "b")
V2 <- c("c", "d")
V3 <- c("e", "f")
```

Second Set:

```
V4 <- c("a", "b", "d")
V5 <- c("e", "f")
V6 <- "c"
```

Now I want to calculate the length of all the possible intersections between vector V1, V2, V3 and vector V4, V5, V6 such that:

Length of intersections of vector V1 and V4, V5, V6 respectively: 2, 0, 0
Length of intersections of vector V2 and V4, V5, V6 respectively: 1, 0, 1
Length of intersections of vector V3 and V4, V5, V6 respectively: 0, 2, 0

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not clear. Can you give a smaller example (two sets of 3 vectors, each with 5 elements) and the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

with arbitary matrix of 100 rows , 11 vectors (representing 11 vectors of 8k elements from yours)

```
m<-matrix(sample(1:1000,1100, replace=T), nrow=100)
mat<-matrix(character(),ncol=11, nrow=11)
for (i in 1:11){
  for (j in i:11){
    mat[i,j]<-paste(intersect(m[,i],m[,j]),collapse=",")
  }
}
```

After Edit, still answered as matrix of 5*11, if its list, of 11 vectors, same way

```
l1<-replicate(5,sample(letters,11))
l2<-replicate(5,sample(letters,11))
mat<-matrix(numeric(),ncol=11, nrow=11)
for (i in 1:11){
  for (j in 1:11){

    mat[i,j]<-length(intersect(l1[i,],l2[j,]))
  }

}



mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    0    2    2    0    0    2    0    1    0     2     1
 [2,]    1    0    2    1    0    1    0    1    2     1     1
 [3,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1     1     0
 [4,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    3    1    1     2     0
 [5,]    2    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1     1
 [6,]    0    1    2    1    0    1    1    1    0     1     1
 [7,]    0    0    2    1    0    0    1    2    0     0     4
 [8,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    2    0     0     2
 [9,]    1    1    0    2    1    2    1    0    1     1     0
[10,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    2    0    3     0     1
[11,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    2    2     0     1
```

as list,

```
ll1<-apply(l1,1,unique)
ll2<-apply(l2,1,unique)
mat<-matrix(numeric(),ncol=11, nrow=11)
for (i in 1:11){
  for (j in 1:11){

    mat[i,j]<-length(intersect(ll1[[i]],ll2[[j]]))
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ananta, I think I explained it incorrectly earlier. What I need is intersection between two sets of 11 vectors.

Comment: if it answered, upvote and choose as answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility, using your example data:

```
# put the two set of vectors in lists
l1 <- list(V1 = c("a", "b"),
           V2 = c("c", "d"),
           V3 = c("e", "f"))

l2 <- list(V4 = c("a", "b", "d"),
           V5 = c("e", "f"),
           V6 = "c")

# create all combinations of list elements
idx <- expand.grid(seq_along(l1), seq_along(l2))

# loop over combinations of list elements with mapply
# for each combination, calculate length of intersect
# put result in matrix 
matrix(mapply(FUN = function(x, y) length(intersect(l1[[x]], l2[[y]])),
       idx[ , 2], idx[ , 1]),
       ncol = length(l2),
       byrow = TRUE,
       dimnames = list(names(l1), names(l2)))

#    V4 V5 V6
# V1  2  0  0
# V2  1  0  1
# V3  0  2  0
```

Comment: +1. Very similar in context, something like `outer(list(V1, V2, V3), list(V4, V5, V6), Vectorize(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y))))`, too.

Comment: @alexis_laz, very nice solution +1! It definitely deserves an own answer. Cheers.